# Not possible to configure LG Ultrawide 25um58-p to 2560x1080 in Ubuntu 19.10 (same issue in 18.4)

Tags: display-resolution, radeon, amd-graphics

I am using Ubuntu 19.10 with the following HW:

1. Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10GHz
2. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [RadeonHD 6400M/7400M Series]
3. LG Ultrawide 25um58-p

The issue is that I cannot use the maximum resolution of this screen, which should be 2560x1080. I have seen many questions and answers related to ultrawide monitors but none of the answers has worked for me.

So far I have tried to add a custom resolution by:

```
$ cvt 2560 1080 60
# 2560x1080 59.98 Hz (CVT) hsync: 67.17 kHz; pclk: 230.00 MHz
Modeline "2560x1080_60.00"  230.00  2560 2720 2992 3424  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync

$ xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_60.00"  230.00  2560 2720 2992 3424  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 "2560x1080_60.00"
$ xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_60.00
```

I have also tried this 2560x1080 resolution with different frequencies (from 40Hz to 65Hz) calculating the modeline with cvt and also using reduce blanking (cvt -r). I have also tried the Modeline that seems to be used when I use this monitor in Windows 10:

"2560x1080_60.00" 185.58 2560 2624 2688 2784 1080 1083 1093 1111 -hsync -vsync

However, none of the previous modelines has worked and I always get one of the following errors:

1. Blank screen
2. Blurry/shaky image:
   [blurry screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prL2d.jpg)
3. Laptop screen crashed and second monitor blurry (as previous case)

Any idea of what I can be doing wrong?

So far the most I have manage to do is using 2160x900 resolution so at least I have 21:9 aspect ratio. This has worked for me even though is not the solution I am after:

```
$ cvt 2160 900 60
# 2160x900 59.91 Hz (CVT) hsync: 55.95 kHz; pclk: 160.25 MHz
Modeline "2160x900_60.00"  160.25  2160 2288 2512 2864  900 903 913 934 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --newmode "2160x900_60.00"  160.25  2160 2288 2512 2864  900 903 913 934 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 "2160x900_60.00"
$ xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2160x900_60.00
```

I have used 2560x1080 with the same laptop using Windows 10 so I assume the graphic card should be able to handle it but I am not sure if the drivers I am using (the default ones with Ubuntu) consider this resolution.

Comment: I have tried with Ubuntu 20.04 and still have the same issue

Comment: Your commands seem to be correct to me, if it's not a hardware issue try updating to the latest drivers using the oibaf ppa. The latest version seems to have [native support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad5uz.png)