# How to report a bug in the open source Radeon graphic driver

Tags: drivers, radeon

After further investigating an issue with the open source Radeon Graphic drivers (issue regarding ultrawide monitor posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228848/not-possible-to-configure-lg-ultrawide-25um58-p-to-2560x1080-in-ubuntu-19-10-sa) I am pretty sure it is due to an issue with the Radeon Graphic drivers, the Caicos in particular. How could I report this bug?

Thanks!

Comment: Radeon 6400M/7400M is a generic name for a series of cards.Note your _actual_ card id, go [here](https://www.amd.com/en/support) to check if that card supports that resolution with your current config ie. cables etc. If you can find bugs about **Mesa** drivers you can report them [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/issues).

Comment: Thanks! The actual card is the AMD Radeon HD 7470M. I have used the same computer and screen with Windows 10 and it was able to display 2560x1080

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, the issue has been reported [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/1121).